# Converting a string to an array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string-conversion

How can I convert a string which is an array of arrays into an actual array of type [[String]]?

For example:

```swift
theString =  "[["Test1", "String"], ["Test2", "String"]]"
```

then the converted array should be as below:

```swift
converted = [["Test1", "String"], ["Test2", "String"]]
```

Is there any way this can be done?

I cannot use `theString.components(separatedBy: ", ")` or `Array(theString)`, I tried both of these and it does not give the expected result.

I am using Swift 5 on Xcode 13.2.1.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is json, what is your original source for this string?

Comment: If it's always JSON-compatible, you can use [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder).

Comment: I'm using an API which returns a response. I convert the response data into a string like the one above. When using JSONDecoder what would be the type I pass in - try decoder.decode(<typeHere>.self, from: data)? I'm not sure if I can pass in a codable struct type because there are no keys?

Comment: `let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([[String]].self, from: data)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I tried this earlier and had errors but just realised that was due to my await/async usage being incorrect. Thanks everyone else for the help!